# Using C# statements in style definition in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

So I try to make my styles dependent from conditions but it mess with almost everthing.
So here is the current state:

```
<style>
    #bodyContainer {
      width: 1024px;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
      background: lightgreen;
    }

    #navbar {
      width: 1024px;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    #layoutContent {
    width: @if (!IsSectionDefined("menu"))
           {
        @:1024
      }
           else
           {
        @:724
      }
      px;
      padding-top: 70px;
      background: lightblue;
    }

      @if (IsSectionDefined("menu"))
      {
        @:#menu {
        @:  padding-top: 70px;
        @:  float:left;
        @:  background:lightgray;
        @:  width: 300px;
        @:}
      }
  </style>
```

It's working (the code, not the layout itself:) ) but:
- the highlight not working in menu section
- the intellisense/highlight not working in the rest of the style tag
- the style inside the if statement looks like a mess
- the generated text looks like a mess:

```
#layoutContent {
width:         724
  px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
}

    #menu {
      padding-top: 70px;
      float:left;
      background:lightgray;
      width: 300px;
    }
```

I really appritiate any idea.

Comment: OMG!!! what are you doing? STOP!! you should reconsider what you are doing, find an easy solution. Dont torture yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`CSS` doesn't work like that, and you shouldn't attempt to mix Razor with CSS.

You should have 2 styles and then based upon the condition apply the class to the HTML elements.

For example, have a separate file for `CSS`:

```
#menu724 {
  padding-top: 70px;
  float:left;
  background:lightgray;
  width: 724px;
}

#menu1024 {
  padding-top: 70px;
  float:left;
  background:lightgray;
  width: 724px;
}
```

Then in your view you could do:

```
   @if (MenuSectionDefined) {
      <div id="menu1024">
          Content
      </div>
   }  else {
      // display the appropriate elements without the `menu` CSS style
     <div id="menu724">
        Content
     </div>
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I make a final solution use the advices I got.
Body part:

```
  <div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    </div>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("menu"))
    {
      <div class="menu">
        @RenderSection("menu")
      </div>
    }
    <div class="container layoutContent @(IsSectionDefined("menu") ? "layoutContent724" : "layoutContent724")">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
```

Style part:

```
.layoutContent {
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.layoutContent724
{
  width: 724px;
}

.layoutContent1024
{
  width: 1024px;
}

.menu {
  padding-top: 70px;
  float: left;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
}
```

I let the question in place in case somebody run in the same situtation.
The final answer to the question I think is "**No way!**". This approach is totally wrong.